# Chinese characters not being rendered on JSP

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, encoding, cjk

I have a jsp say hello.jsp. Now there are 2 use cases

1. the request is redirected to hello.jsp through mainserverlet and in this case, it renders the "editable" text in chinese properly.
2. The second case is when i change the drop down menu on hello.jsp, it "resubmits" the request to itself, instead of mainservlet and in this case the text in chinese is not being displayed properly.

   - The charset=UTF-8 encoding has been set in HTML tag of the jsp.
   - I have tried to see how form is being submitted through javascript and the chinese text remains the same just before "submit". I don't know what happens that it is not being rendered after this.

Any pointers or suggestions?

Comment: Dude is your issue fixed?

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried `page` tag?

Sample:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
```

**Obs:** You need to put this on top of every page you use.

**PS:**
If you are thinking you can add above line in your `header.jsp` file and then `include` header file in your required file like this:

```
<jsp:include page="/resources/header.jsp" />
```

It won't work unless you add that line in every page.

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thank you! Answer should be accepted!

Comment: I added same however it doesnt display the chinese character which is encoded in my jsp. My Jsp file is saved in UTF-8 and i added ur encoding to all my jsp pages.